# python 2.7 – getting this timer object right

Tags: python, python-2.7, time

I'm making a text-based game to practice python.

The following is the code of the Trap scene. In the scene, the player falls into a hole, and if he doesn't react in time (5 seconds), he dies. After starting the timer, I ask for input inside a while loop. I'm seeing, that this code somehow redundant – as i define what happens after the time specified passes twice – but i'm not really sure how to fix it.

```
def b_trap():
    """Trap. I want to implement a timing function here. The player will need to type the appropriate command under a given time. If he cannot make a decision in time, the player dies. Timer object!!!"""
    def b_timeout():
        """If player runs out of time, this is called."""
        b_dead("You fall into the deep hole in the floor, and die when you\nhit the floor fifty meters down. : (")

    print "The floor suddenly disappears behind your feet. You start to fall. What do you do? HURRY!"

    time_to_do_stuff = Timer(5.0, b_timeout)
    time_to_do_stuff.start()

    while time_to_do_stuff.is_alive() is True:
        command = raw_input(" > ")

        if command in (bv_commands['climb'] or bv_commands['jump']):
            time_to_do_stuff.cancel()
            b_not_ready()
        else:
            print "You were saying?"
    else:
        b_timeout()
```

After running this code and not doing anything, `b_timeout()` is executed, but the `raw_input()` prompt remains – i'm asked for input again, but now without the prompt specified in the `raw_input` function(`" > "`).

Could you point out for me what am I missing? I've just started learning python, so please forgive my novice mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` is a blocking function that effectively halts the program until the input is received (waits for a new line/carriage return).

There are two ways around this:

- Record the time before and after the `raw_input`. If the latter is less than five seconds after the former then they responded quickly enough. This approach will have a potentially unwanted behaviour of not showing player death until they respond.
- Run the `raw_input` concurrently in a separate python thread [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929661/non-blocking-raw-input-in-python).