# Dynamically changing the message of raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm looking to move a motorised slider using a Raspberry Pi. However, while debugging the system I was wondering if it is possible to use:

```
target = int(raw_input(<message>))
```

In a way that message could dynamically change before the user inputs a value. For me, it would be great to see the current value that is read from the slider in this `<message>` for example.

And if that isn't possible, is it possible to have a line printed above or below the `raw_input` that remains changing while the system waits for the users' input?

Comment: If you are working on the terminal, you might want to look at this: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html ... You can create text based applications which allow updates to any part of the screen and have very powerful input capabilities.

Comment: Alright, looking into them now! Thanks for that swift response!

Answer (score 0):

You can find that as a non-blocking input.

[Here is a solution from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929661/non-blocking-raw-input-in-python), which uses threads

I did a little modified solution, it still needs some tweaking, but its more or less what you have to do.

```
python
import threading
import time
import random

userInput = ""
finished = False
sensorValue = 100
previousValue = 0

def Listener():
    global userInput, finished, sensorValue
    userInput = raw_input(sensorValue)
    if len(userInput) > 0:
        print(len(userInput))
        finished = True
    else:
        finished = False

while True:
    if sensorValue != previousValue:
        print("Received new slider info. SliderValue is {}".format(sensorValue))
        previousValue = sensorValue
    else:
        print("No new info from slider. Sleeping two seconds.")
    if not finished:
        listener = threading.Thread(target=Listener)
        listener.start()
    else:
        break
    if random.randint(0,1) == 1:
        sensorValue += 10 
    time.sleep(2)
```

See if that answers your question! :)