# Python pause loop on user input

Tags: python, loops, input

Hey I am trying to have a loop be pausable from user input like having a input box in the terminal that if you type `pause` it will pause the loop and then if you type start it will start again.

```
while True:
    #Do something
    pause = input('Pause or play:')
    if pause == 'Pause':
        #Paused
```

Something like this but having the `#Do something` continually happening without waiting for the input to be sent.

Comment: how do you plan to interrupt the "pause"?

Comment: I strongly suspect you're not explaining what you want to accomplish clearly. Anyway, here's one guess, see [Non-Blocking raw_input() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929661/non-blocking-raw-input-in-python).

Comment: @DavidZemens you are right, you can't do it in the same thread! So I created two, one for the loop another for the interrupt

Comment: @martineau that would be another great approach! thanks for sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I get it now, here is a solution with Threads:

```
from threading import Thread
import time
paused = "play"
def loop():
  global paused
  while not (paused == "pause"):
    print("do some")
    time.sleep(3)

def interrupt():
  global paused
  paused = input('pause or play:')


if __name__ == "__main__":
  thread2 = Thread(target = interrupt, args = [])
  thread = Thread(target = loop, args = [])
  thread.start()
  thread2.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly, as `input` blocks everything until it returns.
The [`_thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/_thread.html) module, though, can help you with that:

```
import _thread

def input_thread(checker):
    while True:
        text = input()
        if text == 'Pause':
            checker.append(True)
            break
        else:
            print('Unknown input: "{}"'.format(text))

def do_stuff():
    checker = []
    _thread.start_new_thread(input_thread, (checker,))
    counter = 0
    while not checker:
        counter += 1
    return counter

print(do_stuff())
```