# How can I make a time-sensitive prompt in python? (Interrupting raw_input)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, sleep, raw-input

I am having trouble making a prompt that waits only for a certain amount of time for user input.

I've ended up using threading to start a thread that waits for the input and using the main thread to try and stop the program. The multithreading works just fine, both my raw_input code and my quit() code works perfectly fine...until I throw time.sleep() into the mix to delay the quitting of the program.

It seems like something with time.sleep() makes it wait for the thread to finish; however, I have not been able to find any time.sleep alternatives. I have not been able to find any raw_input alternatives either.

```py
import threading 
import time

def ask():
    print raw_input("What's up?")

def giveUp():
    print "I give up!";
    quit();
    print "I already gave up!";
t1 = threading.Thread(target=ask);
t1.daemon = False;
t1.start()
time.sleep(0.1);
giveUp();
```

I expect the output "What's up" followed after a little bit by "I give up!" followed by the program quitting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929661/non-blocking-raw-input-in-python

Comment: Maybe it's just how Windows works the but "sleep" never ends

Comment: you should find on internet special functon which checks if key was pressed but it doesn't wait for key. It can be called `keypress` or `getchar` or `getch`. Using this function you can create loop which checks time then it checks key and go back to beginning of this loop or exit loop.

Comment: [Python nonblocking console input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408560/python-nonblocking-console-input)

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to do this in Python, but there are several potential solutions. One of the cleaner ways is to register an alarm before your call to `raw_input`. Look at the answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335507/keyboard-input-with-timeout-in-python).